# Счетчик на JS. Поясните как работает

Tags: javascript, счетчики

Всем привет. Нашел в интернете скрипт, код которого ниже. Суть его в том, что он поочередно показывает числа от 0 до 60230. Такой счетчик или анимация.... не знаю как назвать. И я вот не понимаю как он работает. Я когда сам начал писать такой счетчик, хотел его написать через цикл. Причем задача стояла написать такой счетчик своими руками для тренировки, не прибегая при этом к библиотекам. В этим скрипте я не понимаю почему после первого выполнения if, скрипт не закрывается и идет дальше, а повторяется до тех пор, пока не выполнит то, что мы хотим. Объясните, пожалуйста.

```js
function scroll(val, el, timeout, step) {
  var i = 0;
  (function() {
    if (i <= val) {
      setTimeout(arguments.callee, timeout);
      document.getElementById(el).innerHTML = i;
      i = i + step;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(el).innerHTML = val;
    }
  })();
}

scroll(60203, 'shethik-cifra', 10, 60);
```

```html
Нам доверяют:
<div class="shethik-cifra" id="shethik-cifra"></div>
```

Comment: почитайте про setTimeout и setInterval

Comment: А `setInterval()`

Comment: К `setTimeout` ещё нужно глянуть `arguments.callee`.

Comment: А вообще после if функция как раз закрывается (можете добавить `console.log` в конец обоих ф-ций). Просто она вызывается заново, много раз.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте начал с форматирования.